# Prove A=(A intersection B) U (A-B) .

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that $A=(A \cap B) \cup (A-B)$ , using $A \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup (A-B)$ and vice versa.

Comment: What details you need?

Answer (score 4):

$(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap \overline{B})$

By a [Distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) $=A\cap(B\cup \overline{B})$

By a [Complement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) $=A\cap U$

By an [Identity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) $=A$.

Comment: This answers the question.

Could you please prove that $ A \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup (A-B) $ , That will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try a truth table, or possibly consider cases. If a point belongs to A, it can either belong to B or not belong to B.... if it does.... if it does not.... So the set A = .......

Comment: I did that way. But Actually I wanted to prove this using $A \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup (A-B) $  and $(A \cap B) \cup (A-B) \subseteq A $, That will prove that $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A-B) $